# SSIS 2008 - load a single flat files with double header with double rows

Tags: ssis, sql-server-2008-r2, header, flat-file

I'm trying to make a SSIS 2008 package for load into SQL Server DB the data from a flat file.
The flat file format is a little bit particular:

```
EUR;EURIB ;10/03/2016;
Date Rif;   Date;     Days;     Rate;      Discount
10/03/2016;11/03/16;1       ;-0.28895948;100.00079167;
10/03/2016;14/03/16;4       ;-0.29656554;100.00325009;
....
....
....
EUR;GOVIT ;10/03/2016;
Date Rif;   Date;      Days;    Rate;      Discount
10/03/2016;11/03/16;1       ;-0.28895948;100.00079167;
10/03/2016;14/03/16;4       ;-0.29656554;100.00325009;
....
....
....
```

I've marked in bold the two header composed of two rows.
I would put in a variable the first line for each header (for example EUR;GOVIT ;10/03/2016;) and load the rows under the second row (Date Rif;   Date;      Days;    Rate;      Discount) of each header in the same table.
It would seem a mission impossible!
Someone can help me,please?

Thanks in advance!!!

Answer (score 0):

I would do this in a script transformation.   I doubt there is any other way.

Answer (score 0):

One way to do it would be to use a script task to edit the file.  Open the file, confirm that the first line looks like a normal first-line-of-header; delete this line; save the file.  Then import the file - which now has just one header line -  as usual.